# QGIS increase number of recent selections

Tags: qgis, select-by-expression

is there any possibilty to increase the number of recent selections in the menu **select by expression**?
I can´t store more than 20 selections. If I create a new selection, the oldest selection is overwritten.

Or is there a way to create a own group menu, like **Recent(Selection)**, with a own description and selection? 
I use the QGIS Version 3.4.8 LTR 
[image]

Comment: I'm with @she_weeds here. I guess there is not much to do to increase the number of recent items (20), basically because it is [hardcoded](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/4fe477f2b4f38350116e6e0776d6412cd9b05cba/src/gui/qgsexpressiontreeview.cpp#L488). Regarding the other option, I think that would require some effort. If you're interested and you won't migrate soon, you could consider hiring a dev for that. :)

Answer (score 7):

Consider upgrading to QGIS 3.12 - you can [save and load user expressions](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog312/index.html#feature-stored-expressions), so if you've got one that you use frequently you don't need to scroll through recent (or save them in an external text file...)

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot to say that I use QGIS 3.4.8 LTR. An upgrade is planed in my company in 4 months. Therefore I use another way, to solve my problem

Comment: Given that the problem has for all intents and purposes been "solved" with this update, I suspect your best option might be to just wait until your company updates or try to bring that date forward. It's a far easier solution than paying a dev to put in so much effort for something that's going to become irrelevant in 4 months and is a questionable UI choice (>20 recents becomes very cluttered). In the interim, you might have to resort to simpler workarounds like pasting commonly used expressions in text files.